# Storyboard changes not updating in iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

It is a few days that I have this problem and I have not managed to solve it..

I completed a storyboard for iPhone 5, now I've created a new storyboard to iPhone 6, I copied the various ViewController from the storyboard for iPhone 5 and I made some changes.

Now i run my app on iPhone 6 Simulator and **no change** I've made is visible!

I attach some screenshot:

[image]

for example I change the background color of UICollectionView in Blue, but this is the result:

[image]

I tried to Reset Simulator, delete DerivedData folder, restart Xcode, delete Storyboard 6 and re-add, **I do not know what else to try, I never encountered this kind of problem**

I tried with Xcode 6.4, now I upgraded to Xcode 7 but the problem there is still...

**EDIT**:

in AppDelegate I grab the right storyboard in this way:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

 _storyboard = [self grabStoryboard];

 //login-registrati view
lvc = (LoginController *)[_storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];

tabbarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

if (isLogged == YES) {

    self.window.rootViewController = tabbarController;

}
else {

    self.window.rootViewController = lvc;
}

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

...
}

- (UIStoryboard *)grabStoryboard {

int screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
UIStoryboard *storyboard;

switch (screenHeight) {

        // iPhone 4s
    case 480:
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main3.5" bundle:nil];
        break;

        // iPhone 5s
    case 568:
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        break;

        // iPhone 6
    case 667:
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main6" bundle:nil];
        break;

        // iPhone 6 Plus
    case 736:
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main6+" bundle:nil];
        break;
}

return storyboard;
}
```

I know that the Simulator get the right storyboard is that in some ViewController I can see the changes, but if I change the ViewController related to UITabbarController that is the root view controller, there isn't changes on simulator...

Comment: A good place to start would be to describe what you have done to make sure that the other storyboard is going to be used.

Comment: @A-Live in appdelegate based on height of screen i pick the right storyboard, i know that the simulator get the right storyboard because if i change the name of Storyboard 6 and launch the app, it crashes because can't find the storyboard.. this should be enough?

Comment: maybe u forgot to change the main interface setting in xcode ?

Comment: please post the related code.

Comment: @Mr.T i've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a property for UIViewController:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *initialViewController;
```

and do this after you get the new storyboard reference:

```
_storyboard = [self grabStoryboard];
self.initialViewController = [_storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

and then change your rootview

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = self.initialViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Edit:

I even tried your way. And it worked too.Please make sure you have set the view controller identifier in xcode and it matches to "login"

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
lvc = (LoginController *)[_storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
 self.window.rootViewController = lvc;
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

From the documentation:

**instantiateInitialViewController**

> Instantiates and returns the initial view controller in the view
>   controller graph.
>
> Typically, you use this method only when transitioning to the initial view controller in a different storyboard file.

Edit Ilario:

I accepted your answer because it put me in the right direction, I solved changing in this way:

`tabbarController = (UITabbarController *)[_storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];`

Comment: thanks for your answer, i've edited my question and I added how I set the initial view controller in app delegate

Comment: I accepted your answer because it put me in the right direction, I solved changing in this way:  tabbarController = (UITabbarController *)[_storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

Comment: you can edit my answer and include the working part :)